# Creating a New Pandas Grouped Object

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

In some transformations, I seem to be forced to break from the Pandas dataframe grouped object, and I would like a way to return to that object.

Given a dataframe of time series data, if one groups by one of the values in the dataframe, we are given an underlying dictionary from key to dataframe.
Being forced to make a Python dict from this, the structure cannot be converted back into a Dataframe using the .from_dict() because the structure is key to dataframe.
The only way to go back to Pandas without some hacky column renaming is, to my knowledge, by converting it back to a grouped object.
Is there any way to do this?

If not, how would I convert a dictionary of instance to dataframe back into a Pandas datastructure?

EDIT ADDING SAMPLE::

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=10, freq='10m')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':pd.Series(randn(len(rng)), index=rng), 'b':pd.Series(randn(len(rng)), index=rng)})
// now have dataframe with 'a's and 'b's in time series
for k, v in df.groupby('a'):
  df_dict[k] = v
// now we apply some transformation that cannot be applied view aggregate, transform, or apply
// how do we get this back into a groupedby object?
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to achieve?  If you have grouped your DataFrame, what data structure to you want to go "back" to other than the original DataFrame that you already have?

Comment: Added example in the edit

Comment: Your example still doesn't really clarify.  You say in the question that you want to convert it back into a DataFrame, but your example doesn't say anything about that.  Also, it would be helpful if you could provide an example (even just a small "toy" one) of what you want the actual result to be.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand OP's question correctly, you want to group a dataframe by some key(s), do different operations on each group (possibly generating new columns, etc.) and then go back to the original dataframe.

Modifying you example (group by random integers instead of floats which are usually unique):

```
np.random.seed(200)
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=10, freq='10m')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng), 'b':pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)})
df['group'] = np.random.randint(3,size=(len(df)))
```

Usually, If I need single values for each columns per group, I'll do this (for example, sum of 'a', mean of 'b')

```
In [10]: df.groupby('group').aggregate({'a':np.sum, 'b':np.mean})
Out[10]: 
              a         b
group                    
0     -0.214635 -0.319007
1      0.711879  0.213481
2      1.111395  1.042313

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

However, if I need a series for each group,

```
In [19]: def func(sub_df):
        sub_df['c'] = sub_df['a'] * sub_df['b'].shift(1)
        return sub_df
   ....: 

In [20]: df.groupby('group').apply(func)
Out[20]: 
                   a         b  group         c
2000-01-31 -1.450948  0.073249      0       NaN
2000-11-30  1.910953  1.303286      2       NaN
2001-09-30  0.711879  0.213481      1       NaN
2002-07-31 -0.247738  1.017349      2 -0.322874
2003-05-31  0.361466  1.911712      2  0.367737
2004-03-31 -0.032950 -0.529672      0 -0.002414
2005-01-31 -0.221347  1.842135      2 -0.423151
2005-11-30  0.477257 -1.057235      0 -0.252789
2006-09-30 -0.691939 -0.862916      2 -1.274646
2007-07-31  0.792006  0.237631      0 -0.837336

[10 rows x 4 columns]
```

I'm guess you want something like the second example. But the original question wasn't very clear even with your example.